# Resizing image view and movie player controller in xcode when orientation changes

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiimageview, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app i have an image view in one view controller and a movie player in other view controller.Now i want to display the image or movie in both mode i.e in portrait mode and in landscape mode .How can i define frame for each and how do i notify it when the view changes its position from one to other.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the documentation for UIViewController and look at the Responding to View Rotation Events Methods like: `- willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` You can put your code for setting the new frame sizes in those functions along with any notification functions you want. `player.view.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);`

Answer (score 2):

```
MPMoviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,280,440);
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

and image in `UIImageView` in center have transparent background

this is for iPhone